# range versions for std::inclusive_scan and std::partial_sum?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I don't see `std::ranges::inclusive_scan` and `std::ranges::partial_sum` on cppreferences. They didn't make it into C++20? Will they be coming to C++23?

Comment: This may help: [A plan for C++23 ranges, section 4.2.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html#stdpartial_sum-rangespartial_fold-and-stdinexclusive_scan).